# c# Excel AddIn, find content file path when excuting

Tags: c#, vsto, clickonce

I am using VSTO to build an Excel AddIn. In this project, I also added some python `.py` scripts to do some data manipualtion.

The whole project is a C# project, all the .py files are taken as **content files** of the project, in detail, what I did is setting Properities-Build Action as 'Content', setting Properities-Copy to Output Directory as 'Copy always'.

However, **after publish with clickonce**, when executing, I couldn't find where the content files are. I already tried like: `Application.StartupPath`, but did't work. I really need to **find the content files path** and step into them.

Thanks in advance to anyone who take time to see my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Publish page of an office add-in project doesn't have an `Application Files` button which means you can not include some files in the click once installer in the way that you do it for applications. As an option, you can put your files as embedded resources and then at startup of the add-in, extract them from resources and copy them to add-in output directory.

To do so, you can add your file to `Resources.resx` and then at `StartUp` of your add-in, extract the file from resources and save it to the deployment directory and use it.

```
var assemblyLocation = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
var assemblyFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyLocation);
var file = System.IO.Path.Combine(assemblyFolder , "test.py");
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(file))
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(file, Properties.Resources.test);
```

Now the file is in the path specified in `file` variable.

Comment: `Resources.resx` file is located under the project node under `Properties` folder. To add a file to the `Resources.resx`, it's enough open `Resources.resx` i design mode and then copy a file from windows explorer and paste it in designer of resource. Also you can use Add Existing File menu under the Add Resource Button. And then the file will be accessible with its name and as `byte[]`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I am now trying to do an experiment.

Comment: I used the trick without any problem, so let me know if you had any problem applying the solution :)

Comment: actually by setting Properities-Copy to Output , after publish, I already have a 'Test.txt.deploy' file in 'publish\application files' path. Do I still need to put the file into `Resources.resx`? If I don't need to do that, how to change the code above?

Comment: Forget about trying to include the file in `publish\application files`. Just follow what is said in the answer. It's a different solution.

Comment: Sure! It's there! Although I failed letting c# to read python, but I manually checked that the python file is at the path! I will then try to figure out what happened to c# reading python script. Thank you very much!